# Is there a way to play a sound when you load the screen using reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I'm making a website using react for the first time. I would like when you first load the site my mp3 sound plays once and just stops. Here is my react code so far

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import {render} from 'react-dom';
  import Sound from 'react-sound'
  import './styles.scss';
  import sun from "/src/Images/cuteMovingSun.gif"
  import hereComesTheSun from '/src/Images/HereComesTheSunEdit.mp3'
  import useSound from 'use-sound';


const Title = () => {
 return <div>Good Morning, Sunshine!</div>;
 };

const [play] = useSound('hereComesTheSun');


render(<Title />, document.getElementById('root'));
render( <img className = "sun" src={ sun }/>, document.getElementById('mySun'));
```

I'm still new to react so I'm still unclear on a lot of things.

Comment: `useEffect(() => { play() }, [])` (assuming `use-sound` does not handle that already and that you have the appropriate plugins to read an MP3 as binary or - better - as URL) but side note: those two `render()` are pretty suspicious...

Comment: ah yes this is my first time ever making a website completely from scratch, including my webpack. Thanks for commenting on the render mess I had, I went back and refractor my code so now it only has one render.